# How to repeat same network request multiple times with different parameters in rxjs (Angular)?

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, observable, mat-table

I have a mat-table element and a `mat-paginator` element below. 
The table is filled with data from API. 
My API returns 10 elements by request by default, but I need to display 25 elements in my table, hence I need to make 3 API requests to fill the mat-table.

**How to repeat the call to API, with different argument and then return combined all three responses into one observable?**

In my case - I want to repeat `getPlanetsPage(pageNumber)` with different `pageNumber`, so this is the tricky part (I tried to solve this by `repeat()`...):

```js
return this.planetService.getPlanetsPage(dontKnowHowToDoItArg)
  .pipe(
    repeat(Math.ceil(this.paginator.pageSize / this.countOfPlanetsPerPage))
  );
```

Whole code from  ngAfterViewInit() :

```js
this.paginator.page
  .pipe(
    startWith({}),
    switchMap((paginatorData) => {
      this.isLoadingResults = true;

      const indexOfFirstElementToRenderInTable = this.paginator.pageSize * this.paginator.pageIndex;
      if (this.planets[indexOfFirstElementToRenderInTable]) {

        this.planetsToRender = this.planets.slice(indexOfFirstElementToRenderInTable, this.paginator.pageSize * (this.paginator.pageIndex + 1));
        return EMPTY;
      } else {
        return this.planetService.getPlanetsPage(dontKnowHowToDoItArg)
          .pipe(
            repeat(Math.ceil(this.paginator.pageSize / this.countOfPlanetsPerPage))
          );
      }
    }),
    map(planetsPage => {
      this.isLoadingResults = false;
      this.isRateLimitReached = false;
      this.resultsLength = planetsPage.count;
      return planetsPage.results;
    }),
    catchError(() => {
      this.isLoadingResults = false;
      this.isRateLimitReached = true;
      return of([]);
    })
  ).subscribe((planetsArr: Planet[]) => {
    this.planets.push(...planetsArr);
    const indexOfFirstElementToRenderInTable = this.paginator.pageSize * this.paginator.pageIndex;

    this.planetsToRender = this.planets.slice(indexOfFirstElementToRenderInTable, this.paginator.pageSize * (this.paginator.pageIndex + 1));
    this.requestNo++;
  });
```

http service get method:

```js
getPlanetsPage(pageNumber): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient.get(this.planetsBasicPageUrl, {
    params: new HttpParams()
      .set('page', pageNumber.toString())
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you specify element amount in you API without using default behavior (10 elements)? Or, can you change default element amount in your table to fit to default behavior (10 elements) of your API? So, then you avoid difficult processing.

Comment: @Yeheshuah I am using https://swapi.dev/. I need to get planets. As far as I know I can't specify the amount of elements in response from API. I think this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57269110/how-do-i-loop-through-multiple-pages-in-an-api is similar to my problem and maybe this approach (with do-while) is proper, but how do I get this behaviour with rxjs?

Comment: Could you create a StackBlitz demo?

Comment: I guess, the answer to my question is to use expand -> https://ncjamieson.com/understanding-expand/

Answer (score 1):

There is an rxjs operator dedicated for recursive calls, check [EXPAND](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/expand). Here is what will work for you

```
import { from, EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { expand, tap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
...



let results = [] // to concatenate your data each time
let pageNumber = 1; // to count your calls, you need 3 calls so it will be your stop condition



getPlanetsPage(pageNumber): Observable<any> {
 return this.httpClient.get(this.planetsBasicPageUrl, {
   params: new HttpParams()
  .set('page', pageNumber.toString())
 });
}


getPlanetsPage(1).pipe(
  tap(res => {
       this.pageNumber++; 
       results = results.concat(res)  // on success add new results to our array
     }),
  expand((_) => this.pageNumber <=3 
         ? getPlanetsPage(this.pageNumber)
         : EMPTY;
  )
).subscribe(console.log)
```

it's short and clean, you can check my post on dev.to about recursive calls https://dev.to/fatehmohamed14/recursive-http-calls-the-rxjs-way-d61

Answer (score 0):

Hope [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vwysfz?file=src/app/app.component.ts) helps.

```
// demonstrate combining 3 API requests into 1
loadPage(i: number) {
  this.result$ = combineLatest(
    [i * 3, i * 3 + 1, i * 3 + 2].map((i) => this.getAPI(i))
  ).pipe(map(([a, b, c]) => [...a, ...b, ...c]));
}

// simulate an API request
getAPI(page = 0) {
  let pageResult = [];
  for (let i = page * 10; i < (page + 1) * 10; i++) {
    pageResult.push({
      row: i,
      text: (Math.random() * Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).toString(36),
    });
  }
  return of(pageResult)
    .pipe(delay(Math.random() * 200 + 200)); // simulate variant response times
}
```